# How to use python Mock side_effect to act as a Class method in unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am testing a custom API in python that makes http requests, but I don't want to make a request to the real external system every time I run the unit tests.  I am using python's mock library with a side_effect function to dynamically fake the API response.  How do I get the side_effect method to behave like a class method?

```
import requests

class MyApiClass():
    def make_request(self, params):
        return requests.get('http://someurl.com', params=params)

    def create_an_object(self, params):
        return self.make_request(params)
```

---

```
import unittest, mock

def side_effect_func(self, params):
    if params['name'] == 'Specific Name':
        return {'text': 'Specific Action'}
    else:
        return {'text': 'General Action'}

class MyApiTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(MyApiTest, self).setUp()
        mocked_method = mock.Mock(side_effect=side_effect_func)
        MyApiClass.make_request = mocked_method

    def test_create_object(self):
        api = MyApiClass()
        params = {'name': 'Specific Name'}
        r = api.create_an_object(params) # Complains that two arguments are needed!
        self.assertEqual(r['text'], 'Specific Action')
```

---

I get this error

```
TypeError: side_effect_func() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

but I want `side_effect_func` to pass `api` as the first argument.  Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to just make your mock method take a single argument, then reference `MyApiClass` statically within the mock method itself.  Otherwise, you could try mocking the class object itself (basically making a mock metaclass) or maybe using a factory that utilizes `partial` to build a mock class method on the fly.  But if the single argument/static reference method would work for you, that seems the best to me.

Also, from the Mock docs, there's [mocking an unbound method using patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#mocking-unbound-methods), which looks like it may be more what you need.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I think the mocking an unbound method with patch is what I need. If not, your suggestion of hardcoding the MyApiClass should work.

Comment: @silas-ray The anchor in your link to the Python docs no longer exists and I can't find the word "unbound" anywhere (in any version of Python 3): are you able to update it?

Comment: @AllanLewis Yeah, Python 3 eliminated unbound methods all together.  It should just collapse down to patching the function on the class.